# Slicing a vector in R gives weird output

Tags: r

```
(1:10)[2:5]
# [1] 2 3 4 5
(1:10)[2 + 1:5 + 1]
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8
(1:10)[(2 + 1):(5 + 1)]
# [1] 3 4 5 6
(1:10)[10 + 1:5 + 1]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

I am learning how list access works in R. The second case from the above looks weird. Can someone explain how that pattern is working ?

`(1:10)[2 + 1:5 + 1]`

Comment: 1+3 = 4, 2+3 = 5. You are adding three to every value in 1:5 then indexing

Comment: @W.Dodge Why does `(1:10)[10 + 1:5 + 1]` give `NA NA NA NA NA` then ? It should ideally be indexing `1:5` and adding `11` ?

Comment: Because you have added 11 to 1:5 which generates 12,13,14,15,16. You then index 1:10 by those five values which are out of range and get five NAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Vector Math

R allows for vectors to be treated like individual numbers. Here is a [link](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/vector-arithmetics) to nice tutorial on vector math. I bet you already knew this but the configuration was just a little unusual in this case. Your test case basically adds three (1+2) to the vector 1:5 then indexes.

## Test:

`> (1:10)[1+1:5+2] == (1:10)[1:5+3]
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`